# Where is techiyas hameisim alluded to in the Torah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, resurrection-of-the-dead

I have heard it said (without a source) that one who does not believe that the concept of techiyas hameisim can be learned out of the Torah is a heretic. Where does this idea come from?

Furthermore, if the above is true, where can I find an allusion to the concept of techiyas hameisim in the Torah? This is not a challenge rather I want an answer when confronted.

Comment: Interestingly, the Christian Bible in Mark 20 has Jesus bringing an answer to my question, but as that is not necessarily a Jewish source I did not mention it. I do like the answer provided, though. Perhaps there is a Jewish text which makes the same "gezeirah shavah"?

Comment: About the answer in the Christian Bible, the source is Luke 20, and the words are paralleled in [Midrash Mishlei 17, 19](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_(%D7%91%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8)_%D7%99%D7%98), albeit in a different context, not about resurrection. (Found through a search which turned up [this book](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=iZC-tdB35bAC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425&dq=god+of+the+living+luke+rabbinic+source&source=bl&ots=2Qm6o0lj8H&sig=gAlMOCeDTSi6-Wf-fXVRZgPqEr4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgqpOuwPPbAhWJ1RQKHf8hBaIQ6AEIRDAE#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: @ba Thanks! And btw, I made a mistake. The same thing can be found in Mark **12**, not 20. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The idea I believe you are alluding to is stated in the first mishnah of the chapter known as Cheilek in Masechet Sanhedrin. (It's either the tenth or eleventh chapter depending on which edition you are looking at.)

[Mishnah Sanhedrin 10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1?lang=bi) (with translation from Sefaria):

> וְאֵלּוּ שֶׁאֵין לָהֶם חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, הָאוֹמֵר אֵין תְּחִיַּת הַמֵּתִים מִן הַתּוֹרָה
>
> These have no share in the World to Come: One who says that [the belief of] resurrection of the dead is not from the Torah

The gemara commenting on this mishnah (Sanhedrin 90b - 92a) provides many proof-texts for *techiyat hameitim* from verses in Tanach. Following @Kazi bácsi's suggestion, I have summarized them in list format here. If you want the details of how the gemara derives *techiyat hameitim* from these verses, see below the line.

1. [Bamidbar 18:28](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0418.htm#28) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.2?lang=bi)

   > כֵּ֣ן תָּרִ֤ימוּ גַם־אַתֶּם֙ תְּרוּמַ֣ת יְהוָ֔ה מִכֹּל֙ מַעְשְׂרֹ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֣ר תִּקְח֔וּ מֵאֵ֖ת בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל וּנְתַתֶּ֤ם מִמֶּ֨נּוּ֙ אֶת־תְּרוּמַ֣ת יְהוָ֔ה **לְאַֽהֲרֹ֖ן הַכֹּהֵֽן**׃
2. [Shemot 6:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0206.htm#4) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.7?lang=bi)

   > וְגַ֨ם הֲקִמֹ֤תִי אֶת־בְּרִיתִי֙ אִתָּ֔ם **לָתֵ֥ת לָהֶ֖ם** אֶת־אֶ֣רֶץ כְּנָ֑עַן אֵ֛ת אֶ֥רֶץ מְגֻֽרֵיהֶ֖ם אֲשֶׁר־גָּ֥רוּ בָֽהּ׃
3. [Devarim 31:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0531.htm#16) – [Sanhedrin](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi) [90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.14?lang=bi)

   > וַיֹּ֤אמֶר יְהוָה֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה **הִנְּךָ֥ שֹׁכֵ֖ב עִם־אֲבֹתֶ֑יךָ וְקָם֩** הָעָ֨ם הַזֶּ֜ה וְזָנָ֣ה ׀ אַֽחֲרֵ֣י ׀ אֱלֹהֵ֣י נֵֽכַר־הָאָ֗רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֨ר ה֤וּא בָא־שָׁ֨מָּה֙ בְּקִרְבּ֔וֹ וַֽעֲזָבַ֕נִי וְהֵפֵר֙ אֶת־בְּרִיתִ֔י אֲשֶׁ֥ר כָּרַ֖תִּי אִתּֽוֹ׃
4. [Yeshayahu 26:19](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1026.htm#19) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi)

   > **יִֽחְי֣וּ מֵתֶ֔יךָ נְבֵֽלָתִ֖י יְקוּמ֑וּן** הָקִ֨יצוּ וְרַנְּנ֜וּ שֹֽׁכְנֵ֣י עָפָ֗ר כִּ֣י טַ֤ל אוֹרֹת֙ טַלֶּ֔ךָ **וָאָ֖רֶץ רְפָאִ֥ים תַּפִּֽיל**׃
5. [Shir HaShirim 7:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3007.htm#10) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi)

   > וְחִכֵּ֕ךְ כְּיֵ֥ין הַטּ֛וֹב הוֹלֵ֥ךְ לְדוֹדִ֖י לְמֵֽישָׁרִ֑ים **דּוֹבֵ֖ב שִׂפְתֵ֥י יְשֵׁנִֽים**׃
6. [Devarim 11:21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0511.htm#21) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi)

   > לְמַ֨עַן יִרְבּ֤וּ יְמֵיכֶם֙ וִימֵ֣י בְנֵיכֶ֔ם עַ֚ל הָֽאֲדָמָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֨ר נִשְׁבַּ֧ע יְהוָ֛ה לַאֲבֹֽתֵיכֶ֖ם **לָתֵ֣ת לָהֶ֑ם** כִּימֵ֥י הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
7. [Devarim 4:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0504.htm#4) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi)

   > וְאַתֶּם֙ הַדְּבֵקִ֔ים בַּֽיהוָ֖ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֑ם **חַיִּ֥ים כֻּלְּכֶ֖ם הַיּֽוֹם**׃
8. [Bamidbar 15:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0415.htm#31) – [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.16?lang=bi)

   > כִּ֤י דְבַר־יְהוָה֙ בָּזָ֔ה וְאֶת־מִצְוָת֖וֹ הֵפַ֑ר הִכָּרֵ֧ת ׀ תִּכָּרֵ֛ת הַנֶּ֥פֶשׁ הַהִ֖וא **עֲוֺנָ֥ה בָֽהּ**׃
9. [Devarim 32:39](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0532.htm#39) – [Sanhedrin 91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.12?lang=bi)

   > רְא֣וּ ׀ עַתָּ֗ה כִּ֣י אֲנִ֤י אֲנִי֙ ה֔וּא וְאֵ֥ין אֱלֹהִ֖ים עִמָּדִ֑י **אֲנִ֧י אָמִ֣ית וַֽאֲחַיֶּ֗ה** 
   >   מָחַ֨צְתִּי֙ וַֽאֲנִ֣י אֶרְפָּ֔א וְאֵ֥ין מִיָּדִ֖י מַצִּֽיל׃
10. [Shemot 15:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0215.htm#1) – [Sanhedrin 91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.14?lang=bi)

    > אָ֣ז **יָשִֽׁיר**־מֹשֶׁה֩ וּבְנֵ֨י יִשְׂרָאֵ֜ל אֶת־הַשִּׁירָ֤ה הַזֹּאת֙ לַֽיהוָ֔ה וַיֹּֽאמְר֖וּ
    >   לֵאמֹ֑ר אָשִׁ֤ירָה לַֽיהוָה֙ כִּֽי־גָאֹ֣ה גָּאָ֔ה ס֥וּס וְרֹֽכְב֖וֹ רָמָ֥ה בַיָּֽם׃
11. [Yehoshua 8:30](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0608.htm#30) – [Sanhedrin 91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.14?lang=bi)

    > אָ֣ז **יִבְנֶ֤ה** יְהוֹשֻׁ֨עַ֙ מִזְבֵּ֔חַ לַֽיהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל בְּהַ֖ר עֵיבָֽל׃
12. [Tehillim 84:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2684.htm#5) – [Sanhedrin 91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.16?lang=bi)

    > אַ֭שְׁרֵי יֽוֹשְׁבֵ֣י בֵיתֶ֑ךָ    ע֝֗וֹד **יְֽהַלְל֥וּךָ** סֶּֽלָה׃
13. [Yeshayahu 52:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1052.htm#8) – [Sanhedrin 91b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.17?lang=bi)

    > ק֥וֹל צֹפַ֛יִךְ נָ֥שְׂאוּ **ק֖וֹל יַחְדָּ֣ו יְרַנֵּ֑נוּ** כִּ֣י עַ֤יִן בְּעַ֨יִן֙ יִרְא֔וּ בְּשׁ֥וּב יְהוָ֖ה צִיּֽוֹן׃
14. [Devarim 33:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm#6) – [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.5?lang=bi)

    > יְחִ֥י רְאוּבֵ֖ן **וְאַל־יָמֹ֑ת** וִיהִ֥י מְתָ֖יו מִסְפָּֽר׃
15. [Daniel 12:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm#2) – [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.5?lang=bi)

    > **וְרַבִּ֕ים מִיְּשֵׁנֵ֥י אַדְמַת־עָפָ֖ר יָקִ֑יצוּ** אֵ֚לֶּה לְחַיֵּ֣י עוֹלָ֔ם וְאֵ֥לֶּה לַֽחֲרָפ֖וֹת לְדִרְא֥וֹן עוֹלָֽם׃
16. [Daniel 12:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm#13) – [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.5?lang=bi)

    > וְאַתָּ֖ה לֵ֣ךְ לַקֵּ֑ץ וְתָנ֛וּחַ **וְתַֽעֲמֹ֥ד לְגֹרָֽלְךָ֖ לְקֵ֥ץ הַיָּמִֽין**׃
17. [Mishlei 30:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2830.htm#16) – [Sanhedrin 92a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.22?lang=bi)

    > **שְׁאוֹל֮ וְעֹ֪צֶ֫ר רָ֥חַם**    אֶ֭רֶץ לֹא־שָׂ֣בְעָה מַּ֑יִם וְ֝אֵ֗שׁ לֹא־אָ֥מְרָה הֽוֹן׃

---

For those that want all the details, the relevant sections of Sanhedrin 90b - 92a with translations from Sefaria:

[First, we have](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.2?lang=bi) (1):

> אמר ר' יוחנן מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (במדבר יח, כח) ונתתם ממנו [את] תרומת ה' לאהרן הכהן וכי אהרן לעולם קיים והלא לא נכנס לארץ ישראל שנותנין לו תרומה אלא מלמד שעתיד לחיות וישראל נותנין לו תרומה מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> Rabbi Yoḥanan says: From where is the resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from this verse, as it is stated with regard to teruma of the tithe: “And you shall give the teruma of the Lord to Aaron the priest” (Numbers 18:28). And does Aaron exist forever so that one can fulfill the mitzva by giving him the teruma of the tithe? But is it not so that Aaron did not enter Eretz Yisrael, the only place where the people would give him teruma? Rather, the verse teaches that Aaron is destined to live in the future and the Jewish people will give him teruma. From here it is derived that the resurrection of the dead is from the Torah.

[Further on the same page](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.7?lang=bi) (2):

> תניא ר' סימאי אומר מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (שמות ו, ד) וגם הקימותי את בריתי אתם לתת להם את ארץ כנען לכם לא נאמר אלא להם מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> It is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Simai says: From where is resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from a verse, as it is stated with regard to the Patriarchs: “I have also established My covenant with them to give to them the land of Canaan” (Exodus 6:4). The phrase: To give to you the land of Canaan, is not stated, as the meaning of the verse is not that God fulfilled the covenant with the Patriarchs when he gave the land of Canaan to the children of Israel; rather, it is stated: “To give to them the land of Canaan,” meaning to the Patriarchs themselves. From here is it derived that the resurrection of the dead is from the Torah, as in the future the Patriarchs will come to life and inherit the land.

[And immediately following](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.8?lang=bi) (3–7):

> שאלו מינין את רבן גמליאל מניין שהקדוש ברוך הוא מחיה מתים אמר להם מן התורה ומן הנביאים ומן הכתובים ולא קיבלו ממנו
>
> Heretics asked Rabban Gamliel: From where is it derived that the Holy One, Blessed be He, revives the dead? Rabban Gamliel said to them that this matter can be proven from the Torah, from the Prophets, and from Writings, but they did not accept the proofs from him.
>
> מן התורה דכתיב (דברים לא, טז) ויאמר ה' אל משה הנך שוכב עם אבותיך וקם אמרו לו ודילמא וקם העם הזה וזנה
>
> The proof from the Torah is as it is written: “And the Lord said to Moses, behold, you shall lie with your fathers and arise” (Deuteronomy 31:16). The heretics said to him: But perhaps the verse should be divided in a different manner, and it should be read: “Behold, you shall lie with your fathers, and this people will arise and stray after the foreign gods of the land.”
>
> מן הנביאים דכתיב (ישעיהו כו, יט) יחיו מתיך נבלתי יקומון הקיצו ורננו שוכני עפר כי טל אורות טלך וארץ רפאים תפיל ודילמא מתים שהחיה יחזקאל
>
> The proof from the Prophets is as it is written: “Your dead shall live, my corpse shall arise. Awake and sing, you that dwell in the dust, for your dew is as the dew of vegetation, and the land shall cast out the dead” (Isaiah 26:19). The heretics said to him: But perhaps the prophecy was fulfilled with the dead that Ezekiel revived. No proof may be cited from that verse with regard to any future resurrection.
>
> מן הכתובים דכתיב (שיר השירים ז, י) וחכך כיין הטוב הולך לדודי למישרים דובב שפתי ישנים ודילמא רחושי מרחשן שפוותיה בעלמא כר' יוחנן דאמר ר' יוחנן משום ר"ש בן יהוצדק כל מי שנאמרה הלכה בשמו בעולם הזה שפתותיו דובבות בקבר שנאמר דובב שפתי ישנים
>
> The proof from Writings is as it is written: “And your palate is like the best wine that glides down smoothly for my beloved, moving gently the lips of those that sleep” (Song of Songs 7:10), indicating that the dead will ultimately rise and speak. The heretics said to him: But perhaps merely their lips will move, in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yoḥanan, as Rabbi Yoḥanan says in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Yehotzadak: Anyone in whose name a halakha is stated in this world, his lips move in the grave as if repeating the statement cited in his name, as it is stated: “Moving gently the lips of those that sleep.” No proof may be cited from that verse, as it is unrelated to resurrection.
>
> עד שאמר להם מקרא זה (דברים יא, כא) אשר נשבע ה' לאבותיכם לתת להם לכם לא נאמר אלא להם מיכן לתחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> This exchange continued until Rabban Gamliel stated to them this verse: “That your days may be multiplied, and the days of your children, upon the land that the Lord took an oath to your forefathers to give them” (Deuteronomy 11:21). The phrase: To give you, is not stated; rather, it is stated: “To give them,” to the Patriarchs themselves, as in the future the Patriarchs will come to life and inherit the land. From here resurrection of the dead is derived from the Torah.
>
> וי"א מן המקרא הזה אמר להם (דברים ד, ד) ואתם הדבקים בה' אלהיכם חיים כלכם היום (פשיטא דחיים כולכם היום אלא אפילו ביום שכל העולם כולם מתים אתם חיים) מה היום כולכם קיימין אף לעוה"ב כולכם קיימין
>
> And there are those who say that it is from this following verse that he said to them his ultimate proof: “But you who cleave to the Lord your God every one of you is alive this day” (Deuteronomy 4:4). Wasn’t it obvious with regard to the children of Israel whom God was addressing, that “every one of you is alive this day”? Rather, the meaning of the verse is: Even on the day when everyone is dead you will live; just as today every one of you is alive, so too, in the World-to-Come every one of you will be alive.

[The gemara then repeats one of the sources in a different context](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.14?lang=bi) (3):

> שאלו רומיים את רבי יהושע בן חנניה מניין שהקב"ה מחיה מתים ויודע מה שעתיד להיות אמר להו תרווייהו מן המקרא הזה שנאמר (דברים לא, טז) ויאמר ה' אל משה הנך שוכב עם אבותיך וקם העם הזה וזנה
>
> The Romans asked Rabbi Yehoshua ben Ḥananya: From where is it derived that the Holy One, Blessed be He, revives the dead, and from where is it derived that He knows what is destined to be? Rabbi Yehoshua ben Ḥananya said to them: Both of those matters are derived from this verse, as it is stated: “And the Lord said to Moses, Behold, you shall lie with your fathers and arise; this people will go astray” (Deuteronomy 31:16). This indicates that Moses will die and then arise from the dead and that the Holy One, Blessed be He, knows what the children of Israel are destined to do.

[And further on the same page](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.90b.16?lang=bi) (8):

> תניא א"ר אליעזר בר' יוסי בדבר זה זייפתי ספרי מינים שהיו אומרים אין תחיית המתים מן התורה אמרתי להן זייפתם תורתכם ולא העליתם בידכם כלום שאתם אומרים אין תחיית המתים מן התורה הרי הוא אומר (במדבר טו, לא) הכרת תכרת הנפש ההיא עונה בה הכרת תכרת בעולם הזה עונה בה לאימת לאו לעולם הבא
>
> It is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Eliezer, son of Rabbi Yosei, says: With this following matter, I refuted the books of the Samaritans, as they would say that there is no source for the resurrection of the dead from the Torah. I said to them: You falsified your torah and you accomplished nothing, as you say there is no source for the resurrection of the dead from the Torah, and the Torah states: “That soul shall be excised; his iniquity shall be upon him” (Numbers 15:31). You interpret the phrase “that soul shall be excised” to mean that a sinner will be punished with death in this world. If so, with regard to the phrase “his iniquity shall be upon him,” for when is that destined to be? Is it not for the World-to-Come, i.e., the world as it will exist after the resurrection of the dead? Apparently, there is a World-to-Come and there is an allusion to it in the Torah.

[Then on 91b we have](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.12?lang=bi) (9):

> רבא רמי כתיב (דברים לב, לט) אני אמית ואחיה וכתיב (דברים לב, לט) מחצתי ואני ארפא אמר הקב"ה מה שאני ממית אני מחיה והדר מה שמחצתי ואני ארפא ת"ר אני אמית ואחיה יכול שתהא מיתה באחד וחיים באחד כדרך שהעולם נוהג ת"ל מחצתי ואני ארפא מה מחיצה ורפואה באחד אף מיתה וחיים באחד מיכן תשובה לאומרין אין תחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> Rava raises a contradiction. It is written: “I will kill and I will bring to life” (Deuteronomy 32:39), indicating that God is capable of reviving the dead. And it is written immediately afterward: “I wounded and I will heal,” which indicates that God will only heal the wounded. Rather, it should be understood: The Holy One, Blessed be He, is saying: What I kill, I bring to life, indicating that God revives the dead. And then what I wounded, I will heal.
>
> The Sages taught in a baraita with regard to the verse: “I will kill and I will bring to life.” One might have thought that it means that there will be death for one person and life for one other person, in the typical manner that the world operates. Therefore, the verse states: “I wounded and I will heal.” Just as wounding and healing take place in one person, so too, death and bringing back to life take place in one person. From here there is a response to those who say that there is no resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah.

[Followed by](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.14?lang=bi) (10–11):

> תניא אמר רבי מאיר מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (שמות טו, א) אז ישיר משה ובני ישראל את השירה הזאת לה' שר לא נאמר אלא ישיר מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה כיוצא בדבר אתה אומר (יהושע ח, ל) אז יבנה יהושע מזבח לה' בנה לא נאמר אלא יבנה מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> It is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Meir said: From where is resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from a verse, as it is stated: “Then Moses and the children of Israel will sing this song to the Lord” (Exodus 15:1). It is not stated: Sang, in the verse; rather, the term “they will sing” is stated, indicating that Moses will come back to life and sing the song in the future. From here it is proved that resurrection of the dead is derived from the Torah. On a similar note, you can say: “Then Joshua will build an altar to the Lord God of Israel on Mount Ebal” (Joshua 8:30). It is not stated: Built, in the verse; rather, the term “will build” is stated. From here, resurrection of the dead is derived from the Torah.

[A little later we have](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.16?lang=bi) (12):

> א"ר יהושע בן לוי מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (תהלים פד, ה) אשרי יושבי ביתך עוד יהללוך סלה היללוך לא נאמר אלא יהללוך מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה וא"ר יהושע בן לוי כל האומר שירה בעוה"ז זוכה ואומרה לעולם הבא שנאמר אשרי יושבי ביתך עוד יהללוך סלה
>
> Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says: From where is resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from a verse, as it is stated: “Happy are they who dwell in Your house; they will yet praise You, Selah” (Psalms 84:5). It is not stated: They praised you, in the verse; rather, the term “they will praise you” is stated. From here, resurrection of the dead is derived from the Torah. And Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says: Anyone who recites song to God in this world is privileged and recites it in the World-to-Come, as it is stated: “Happy are they who dwell in Your house; they will yet praise You, Selah.”

[And](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b.17?lang=bi) (13):

> א"ר חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (ישעיהו נב, ח) קול צופיך נשאו קול יחדו ירננו וגו' ריננו לא נאמר אלא ירננו מכאן לתחיית המתים מן התורה וא"ר חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן עתידין כל הנביאים כולן אומרים שירה בקול אחד שנאמר קול צופיך נשאו קול יחדו ירננו
>
> Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba says that Rabbi Yoḥanan says: From where is resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from a verse, as it is stated: “Your watchmen, they raise the voice; together shall they sing, for they shall see eye to eye the Lord returning to Zion” (Isaiah 52:8). It is not stated: They sang, in the verse; rather, the term “together shall they sing” is stated. From here resurrection of the dead is derived from the Torah. And Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba says that Rabbi Yoḥanan says: All the prophets are all destined to recite song in one voice, as it is stated: “Your watchmen, they raise the voice; together shall they sing.”

[On 92a we find](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.5?lang=bi) (14–16):

> אמר רבא מניין לתחיית המתים מן התורה שנאמר (דברים לג, ו) יחי ראובן ואל ימות יחי ראובן בעולם הזה ואל ימות לעולם הבא רבינא אמר מהכא (דניאל יב, ב) ורבים מישני אדמת עפר יקיצו אלה לחיי עולם ואלה לחרפות לדראון עולם רב אשי אמר מהכא (דניאל יב, יג) ואתה לך [לקץ] ותנוח ותעמוד לגורלך לקץ הימין
>
> Rava says: From where is resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah? It is derived from a verse, as it is stated: “Let Reuben live and not die, in that his men become few” (Deuteronomy 33:6). This is interpreted: “Let Reuben live” in this world “and not die” in the World-to-Come. Ravina says that resurrection is derived from here: “And many of those who sleep in the dust of the earth shall awaken, some to everlasting life, and some to reproaches and everlasting disgrace” (Daniel 12:2). Rav Ashi says proof is derived from here: “But go you your way until the end be; and you shall rest, and arise to your lot at the end of days” (Daniel 12:13).

[Finally, further on the page](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.92a.22?lang=bi) (17):

> אמר ר' טבי אמר ר' יאשיה מאי דכתיב (משלי ל, טז) שאול ועוצר רחם ארץ לא שבעה מים וכי מה ענין שאול אצל רחם אלא לומר לך מה רחם מכניס ומוציא אף שאול מכניס ומוציא והלא דברים קל וחומר ומה רחם שמכניסין בו בחשאי מוציאין ממנו בקולי קולות שאול שמכניסין בו בקולות אינו דין שמוציאין ממנו בקולי קולות מיכן תשובה לאומרין אין תחיית המתים מן התורה
>
> Rabbi Tavi says that Rabbi Yoshiya says: What is the meaning of that which is written: “There are three that are never satisfied…the grave, and the barren womb, and earth that does not receive sufficient water” (Proverbs 30:15–16)? And what does a grave have to do with a womb? Rather, they are juxtaposed to say to you: Just as a womb takes in and gives forth, so too a grave takes in and also gives forth, with the resurrection of the dead.
>
> And are these matters not inferred a fortiori: If with regard to a womb, into which one introduces the embryo in secret, one removes the baby from it accompanied by the loud sounds of the woman crying out during childbirth, then with regard to the grave, into which one introduces the corpse with sounds of wailing and mourning the dead, is it not right that one removes from it the resurrected dead accompanied by the loud sounds of the resurrected multitudes? From here there is a response to those who say: There is no resurrection of the dead derived from the Torah.

Comment: VERY WELL DONE!!

Comment: Your answer is a "keeper" on an interesting subject. I may archive this one for a future Shabbat / Yom Tov shiur.

Answer (score 6):

Daniel 12/2

**ורבים מישני אדמת־עפר יקיצו** אלה לחיי עולם ואלה לחרפות לדראון עולם

**Many of those that sleep in the dust of the earth will awake**, some to eternal life, others to reproaches, to everlasting abhorrence.

Rashi :**ורבים מישני אדמת עפר יקיצו**. יחיו המתים

If you want one from the Chumash, then there is a hint brought in Rasi on אז ישיר:

אז ישיר משה THEN SANG MOSES — with regard to the usage of the future ישיר,... But so far as its Midrashic explanation is concerned our Rabbis, of blessed memory, said: from here (i. e. from the fact that the future tense is used) we may derive an intimation that the tenet of the Resurrection of the Dead is from the Torah (is alluded to, although only by inference, in the Torah) (Sanhedrin 91b).